# cakePHP 2.0 Associated models data not being retrieved

Tags: cakephp, model

I have 2 tables, Militia and Injunctions. Militia can have many injunctions and injunctions only belong to one militia. I set those up in the models but when i call a find all for militia the injunctions aren't pulled out.

**Militia model**

```
class Militia extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className'    => 'User',
            'foreignKey'   => 'user_id'
        )
    );

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Injunction' => array(
            'className'     => 'Injunction',
            'foreignKey'    => 'militia_id'
            //'conditions'    => array("not" => array('Injunction.removed' => null))
        )
    );
}
```

**Injunctions model**

```
class Injunction extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Militia' => array(
            'className'    => 'Militia',
            'foreignKey'   => 'militia_id'
        )
    );
}
```

**and the query getting the militia members**

```
$user = $this->Session->read("User");

        $militias = $this->Militia->find('all',
            array(
                'conditions'=>array(
                    "Militia.user_id"   => $user['User']['id'],
                    "Militia.deleted"   => 0
                )
            )
        );
```

**output**

```
    /app/Controller/UsersController.php (line 41)
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Militia' => array(
            'id' => '26',
            'first_name' => 'Chris',
            'last_name' => 'Morris',
            'created' => '2013-02-11 13:45:24',
            'user_id' => '2',
            'status' => '1',
            'deleted' => '0'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'Militia' => array(
            'id' => '31',
            'first_name' => 'John',
            'last_name' => 'Smith',
            'created' => '2013-02-11 14:03:50',
            'user_id' => '2',
            'status' => '0',
            'deleted' => '0'
        )
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'Militia' => array(
            'id' => '32',
            'first_name' => 'test',
            'last_name' => 'user',
            'created' => '2013-02-11 14:21:38',
            'user_id' => '2',
            'status' => '0',
            'deleted' => '0'
        )
    ),
    (int) 3 => array(
        'Militia' => array(
            'id' => '33',
            'first_name' => 'test',
            'last_name' => 'user',
            'created' => '2013-02-11 14:24:02',
            'user_id' => '2',
            'status' => '1',
            'deleted' => '0'
        )
    )
)
```

I've done the same thing before on other projects but for some reason this one time it's not pulling out the associated data. It's probably something stupid like a typo but I've been looking and testing and can't find anything wrong.

Comment: Which is the query you are trying to execute to retrieve the data?

Comment: Show the find statement

Comment: `$user = $this->Session->read("User");
   
   $militias = $this->Militia->find('all',
    array(
     'conditions'=>array(
      "Militia.user_id" => $user['User']['id'],
      "Militia.deleted" => 0
     )
    )
   );`

Comment: I would have thought that would work. Have you tried using the Containable behavior?

Comment: Have you changed the [recursive](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive) setting somewhere?

Comment: Nope not touched Recursive at all.

Comment: Which is the resulting array of data you get? Can you post it in the question please?

Comment: Ok now when i do a find all for users (users have many militia, militia belong to one user) I don't get militia either, this is very weird as I've literally only just started this project and everything is petty much default.

Comment: You say you have 2 tables `militia and injunctions` is militia not plural? this could be giving you problems. Check the inflector lookup... http://inflector.cakephp.org/ look up militia

Comment: `Militia` should be called `MilitiasController` and `Militium`. Also try doing a find without conditions. It could be possible that the Militium you are trying to access does not contain any Injunctions. In that case it could be empty as well. What version of Cake are you using? I assume 2.3.0?

Comment: My militia controller is called MilitiasController, I'm getting the data in the user controller however. I am however confused as to what you are referring to when you mention `Militium`.

I'll have a look at running the query without conditions, however when i do a find all for users without conditions it does similar and doe snot bring out children.

And yes I'm pretty sure I'm on 2.3.0, I'll have a check when I get a chance.

Comment: Something simple: Is the foreign key set correctly the Injunction.militia_id? Or are they maybe all null or something?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check ORM (hasOne, hasMany, belongsTo, hasAndBelongsToMany) definition,
2. Check if foreign key ids are set right
3. Check if there are data's in the table and its related table.
4. Check the results of find without condition
5. Check to see if recursive level is greater than 0
6. To rule out your old cached query issue, set debug level higher to 0
7. Look out in the bottom section of sql dump to see what query is being fired, if it feels ok try same query with SQL away from Cake/Php.